# ElastAlert and Kibana 5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

I am trying to use elastalert with Kibana 5.0 and I see that it says in the documentation for elastalert works for 1.x and 2.x . I have kibana 5.0 and want to know if anyone got elastalert to work with kibana 5.0

Comment: It works fine for me as well with Kibana 5

Answer (score 1):

Elastalert doesn't necessarily interact with Kibana for the most part; but instead directly interacts with the ElasticSearch RESTFul API. Your version of Kibana should be irreverent for 99% of elastalert functionality with the exception of the dashboard `use_kibana_dashboard` configuration option.

If this is the feature you are referring to then you should be aware that Elastalert doesn't officially support ElasticSerach 5.x yet and it will be unlikely that they will be committing an awful lot of effort into that small feature until they do.

If you do wish to use the development codebase for Elastaleart with ES5 support then checkout (no pun intended) the following branch. I have it running on one of my systems and it seems to work well with ES5.0.2.

ES5 Branch: https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/tree/support_es5

**Installation instructions:**

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert.git
$ cd elastalert/
$ git checkout support_es5
$ python setup.py install
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```